# How to inject pojo dependencies using dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have a simple pojo class:

```
public class MySimpleClass {

    private List<String> mDependency;

    public MySimpleClass (List<String> dependency) {
        mDependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to have it created using dependency injection using dagger 2. Right now I have a simple module and component for it:

```
@Module
public class MySimpleClassModule {

    @Provides
    MySimpleClass provideMySimpleClass(List<String> dependency) {
        return new MySimpleClass(dependency);
    }
}

@Component(modules={MySimpleClassModule.class})
public interface MySimpleClassComponent {
}
```

But I'm not sure how can I inject the `List<String>` dependency every time I need to create a new instance of `MySimpleClass`. In the above scenario, it seems I would actually need to add `List<String>` to the constructor of `MySimpleClassModule` and have a new instance of that module every time I need a new instance of `MySimpleClass` with a new `List<String>`. Is that correct? It seems like a lot of overhead in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get to define the constructor of an object it is best to use an `@Inject` constructor. Dagger 2 will automatically know how to instantiate the object so you won't need a `@Provides` annotated method in a module.

```
public class MySimpleClass {

    private List<String> mDependency;

    @Inject
    public MySimpleClass (List<String> dependency) {
        mDependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

Dagger will assume that the parameters of the constructor are dependencies and try to resolve them from the dependency graph. Note that you can only have one `@Inject` annotated constructor per class! If you cannot instantiate the object yourself (e.g. Android Activities/Fragments) you need to use field injection.

In your case it doesn't seem necessary to inject an empty list into `MyClass`. You can just instantiate the list in the constructor. However, when you want to inject `MyClass` into another object it will already be in the object graph.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really solve the problem, I think. In your approach I have now to declare a way to "provide" for my `List<String>` dependency somewhere, like in module.  So I would still need to instantiate a new module every time I need a new instance of `MySimpleClass`.

Comment: Right now, if I just change it like you suggested, I get "error: java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method."

Comment: Like I said, you don't really need to inject your list. Just instantiate it inside of your object.

```public class MySimpleClass {

    private List<String> mDependency;

    @Inject
    public MySimpleClass () {
        mDependency = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.

I assume you got a compilation error with **Dagger** since from question it is not clear if you already have a module that provides this list of strings.

To fix that one you can simply:

```
@Module
public class MySimpleClassModule {

    @Provides
    List<String> provideListDependency() {
        return Arrays.asList("One", "Two");
    }

    @Provides
    MySimpleClass provideMySimpleClass(List<String> dependency) {
        return new MySimpleClass(dependency);
    }
}
```

If you think that providing this list should be part of a different module you can move it. The main thing, that **Dagger** during compilation was able to find how to get this dependency.

If you do not want to create this array over in over you can mark method as `@Singlethon` so dagger will cache it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    String name;
    @Inject
    A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Component
    interface AComponent {
        A getA();
        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder {
            @BindInstance
            Builder provideName(String name);
            A build();
        }
    }
```